# Difference between "last year" and "over the last year"

Tags: present-perfect, phrases, present-continuous

In this sentence,

> The investment in equipment last year ___ a significant increase in sales.

Between "is causing" and "has caused", I think I have to use "has caused". However, my friends told me that if I want to use "has caused", sentence has to be corrected "over the last year", and not "last year". Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not to include ***over the*** before ***last year*** is largely just a stylistic choice, but...

If you *do* include ***over the***, this strongly implies that multiple investments were made *on several occasions, or continuously*. If you *don't* include it, that interpretation is still possible, but it's also possible the entire investment took place on a single occasion.

---

The difference between using (Past<sup>1</sup>) ***has caused*** or (Present) ***is causing*** here is exactly what you'd expect - use the latter if the process is still ongoing, otherwise use the former.

The logic of the real-world situation in the specific example may make it difficult to decide whether you want to describe the "increase in sales" as an ***ongoing*** process, so it might help to consider a more clear-cut alternative...

> 1: *The covid lockdown **is causing** great distress*
> 2: *The covid lockdown **has caused** great distress*

...where #1 strongly implies the lockdown is *still in force* (and people are being distressed *right now*), but #2 could be used *during **or** after* a lockdown (possibly even "after the distress", if that distress is still "relevant" to the current situation).

---

<sup>1</sup> In case this is confusing, note that **Present** Perfect *(**has caused**)* is used to reference ***things which happened in the past,*** but which are either still happening or still relevant at time of speaking. But as pointed out above, it might be a matter of opinion whether "causing an increase in sales" is "relevant" and/or "ongoing" in OP's example.

Comment: No offense meant, but _has caused_ is not past. It is present perfect.

Comment: No offense taken, but you're mistaken. Despite the name, Present Perfect IS a "past tense" verb form. From [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/present-perfect-tense/#:~:text=The%20present%20perfect%20tense%20refers,%2Fhas%20%2B%20the%20past%20participle.): *The **present perfect** tense refers to an action or state that either occurred at an indefinite time in the **past** (e.g., we have talked before) or began in the past and continued to the present time (e.g., he has grown impatient over the last hour).*

Comment: Oh I see. You were talking in reference to the past instances. I get it now. I have read that Grammarly article 10 times or more already. I thought you might have typed the name of the tense incorrectly in a rush. No problem Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Actually, it's good you've flagged it up. Even if *you* can now see what I meant, obviously the name of the tense is potentially confusing for others, so I'll edit to reflect this.